# Why is not every of my parallel ajax-requests using its own XMLHttpReferencer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, dom-events

I want to use parallel ajax-requests to download a few files at the same time. For each download there should be a own progress-bar. For this purpose iI used the xhr-callback of the ajax-function (jQuery) and create a new `XMLHttpRequest()`, subscribe to its progress-Event and return that new `XMLHttpRequest()`.

If I am downloading just one file, this works perfectly, but if I start the second download, its progress-bar shows exact the same value as the progress-bar of the first download. The ajax-success-event is fired simultaneously also.

This means that there is only one instance of the `XMLHttpRequest()`-object, right? How can I solve this?

```
function downloadFile(id) {
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        url: '/Other/TransferTest', // The ASP.NET MVC Controller that is returning the file
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            alert(thrownError);
        },
        xhr: function () {
            // Create new (?) XMLHttpRequest-Object
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // Add progress.EventListener to that new Object
            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                  $('#progressBar' + id).attr('value', Math.round(percentComplete * 100));
                }

            }, false);

            // Return the new Object for use withing the AJAX-Function
            return xhr;
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        complete: function (xhr) {
            alert('complete, id: ' + id);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success, id: ' + id);
        }
    });
}

<div class="mainTabsContent">
    <h2>File Download</h2>
    <button id="downloadFileButton" style="width: 300px;" onclick="downloadFile(1);">Download File 1</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <progress id="progressBar1" style="width: 300px; height: 30px;" value="0" max="100"></progress>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button id="downloadFileButton" style="width: 300px;" onclick="downloadFile(2);">Download File 2</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    .<progress id="progressBar2" style="width: 300px; height: 30px;" value="0" max="100"></progress>
    <br />
</div>
```

The following result is used to return the file in ASP.NET MVC (note: this file has some unperformant lines in it -it is copied and was corrected later):

```
public class DownloadResult : ActionResult
{
    string FullFileName { get; set; }

    public DownloadResult(string fullFileName)
    {
        FullFileName = fullFileName;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        System.IO.Stream iStream = null;

        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(FullFileName);
        long fileLength = f.Length;

        // Buffer to read 10K bytes in chunk:
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[4096];

        // Length of the file:
        int length;

        // Total bytes to read:
        long dataToRead;

        // Identify the file to download including its path.
        string filepath = FullFileName;

        // Identify the file name.
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath);

        try
        {
            // Open the file.
            iStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                        System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read);


            // Total bytes to read:
            dataToRead = iStream.Length;

            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
            context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileLength.ToString());

            // Read the bytes.
            while (dataToRead > 0)
            {
                // Verify that the client is connected.
                if (context.HttpContext.Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    // Read the data in buffer.
                    length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
                    if (length < 4096)
                    {
                        string breakpoint = "";
                    }
                    // Write the data to the current output stream.
                    context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                    // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                    context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();

                    buffer = new Byte[4096];
                    dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
                }
                else
                {
                    //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                    dataToRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Trap the error, if any.
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (iStream != null)
            {
                //Close the file.
                iStream.Close();
            }
            context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Close();
            //context.HttpContext.Response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does each request have its own progress bar if you statically reference `#progressBar1`?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry -this is my fail. I didn't change the code back there. But this isn't changing the behavior since the success-events are fired simultaneously.

Comment: Can you please show the whole code, including the multiple invocations and the progress handling? I suspect the mistake is there, what you posted seems to look fine.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry for the late answer. I updated the code. On the server-side a FileStream is used to return a File. Any ideas?

Comment: So you do call `downloadFile(1); downloadFile(2);`?

Comment: @Bergi Correct. Is this wrong? In production i call with some IDs and stuff -but its simpler to understand this way. Thanks

Comment: No, looks fine. I only would've guessed if that "stuff" are other callbacks you might have some closure problem. If that's not the case, I don't know.

Comment: @Bergi Since the "stuff" is not implemented yet, i am pretty sure there is another problem :( I would also say that the code is correct but still, there is a problem. I will look deeper and answer as soon as i found it. Thank you very much.